# sql syntax error occur?

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, mysql-workbench

```
 string query = "update library_database.members set name='" + txtname.Text + "', Adresss='" + richtxtadress.Text + "',";
 query = query + "Status='" + cmbstatus.SelectedText + "',Type='" + cmbtype.SelectedText + "',";
 query = query + "Date_expiry='" + dateofexpiry.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "',@IMG";
 query=query+"' where id='";
 query = query + txtid.Text + "'";
 cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imgbt));
```

The exception occur SQL Santax error at line 1 near @IMG. Please help how can I solve it?

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: ok but this time i am using this type of query kindly check the syntax error.

Comment: After removing all but the last set statement your query would look like `update [...] set @IMG where [...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forget to column name when you update your `@IMG` value.

It should be something like;

```
query = ... "ColumnName = @IMG" + ...
```

### But please

ALWAYS use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Next time, when you get this kind of *sql syntax* error, first thing you should try is to run your query in your database manager. Then you can easily see what is wrong with your query and how you can fix it.

Comment: @ASIMSHAHID Could you please show your all query with values? And your column types as well?

Comment: string query = "update library_database.members set name='" + txtname.Text + "', Adresss='" + richtxtadress.Text + "',";
 query = query + "Status='" + cmbstatus.SelectedText + "',Type='" + cmbtype.SelectedText + "',";
 query = query + "Date_expiry='" + dateofexpiry.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ",image='@IMG'";
 query=query+"' where id='";
 query = query + txtid.Text + "'";
 cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imgbt));
 it works with out image its working correctly i have checkd bt when i insert image its give error my image coulmn type is blob.